# Given events with start and end timex, how merge events closer than a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `capsules` that hold events localized in time:

```
                 Start                 End
0  2022-01-05 04:35:00 2022-01-05 04:45:00
1  2022-02-04 21:05:00 2022-02-04 21:15:00
2  2022-03-09 04:35:00 2022-03-09 04:45:00
3  2022-03-09 04:35:00 2022-03-09 04:45:00
4  2022-03-09 20:15:00 2022-03-09 20:25:00
5  2022-03-09 20:25:00 2022-03-09 21:15:00
6  2022-04-27 17:05:00 2022-04-27 17:25:00
7  2022-04-27 17:05:00 2022-04-27 17:15:00
8  2022-04-27 21:05:00 2022-04-27 21:55:00
9  2022-04-27 21:05:00 2022-04-27 21:15:00
10 2022-05-06 12:45:00 2022-05-06 12:55:00
11 2022-05-06 12:45:00 2022-05-06 12:55:00
12 2022-05-06 13:15:00 2022-05-06 13:25:00
13 2022-05-06 13:45:00 2022-05-06 13:55:00
14 2022-05-06 16:50:00 2022-05-06 16:50:00
15 2022-05-06 17:35:00 2022-05-06 17:55:00
16 2022-05-06 22:45:00 2022-05-06 22:55:00
17 2022-05-07 00:45:00 2022-05-07 00:55:00
18 2022-05-07 02:15:00 2022-05-07 02:25:00
19 2022-06-21 06:25:00 2022-06-21 06:35:00
20 2022-06-21 19:25:00 2022-06-21 19:35:00
21 2022-06-21 21:35:00 2022-06-21 21:45:00
22 2022-06-22 15:25:00 2022-06-22 15:55:00
23 2022-06-22 16:15:00 2022-06-22 16:25:00
24 2022-06-22 18:30:00 2022-06-22 18:55:00
25 2022-06-22 19:25:00 2022-06-22 19:35:00
26 2022-06-22 21:05:00 2022-06-22 21:15:00
27 2022-06-23 07:35:00 2022-06-23 07:45:00
28 2022-06-23 07:35:00 2022-06-23 07:45:00
29 2022-07-31 18:35:00 2022-07-31 18:45:00
30 2022-07-31 19:05:00 2022-07-31 19:15:00
31 2022-07-31 19:25:00 2022-07-31 19:35:00
32 2022-07-31 22:00:00 2022-07-31 22:00:00
33 2022-07-31 23:55:00 2022-08-01 00:05:00
34 2022-08-03 23:35:00 2022-08-03 23:45:00
35 2022-08-06 07:20:00 2022-08-06 07:20:00
36 2022-08-08 04:35:00 2022-08-08 04:40:00
37 2022-10-17 12:05:00 2022-10-17 12:15:00
38 2022-10-21 19:05:00 2022-10-21 19:15:00
39 2022-10-22 17:35:00 2022-10-22 17:45:00
40 2022-10-23 07:25:00 2022-10-23 07:35:00
41 2022-11-01 18:25:00 2022-11-01 18:45:00
42 2022-11-01 18:25:00 2022-11-01 18:35:00
43 2022-11-01 23:05:00 2022-11-01 23:15:00
44 2022-11-01 23:05:00 2022-11-01 23:25:00
45 2022-11-02 02:35:00 2022-11-02 03:25:00
46 2022-11-02 03:15:00 2022-11-02 03:25:00
47 2022-11-30 23:45:00 2022-11-30 23:55:00
48 2022-11-30 23:45:00 2022-11-30 23:55:00
49 2022-12-01 00:15:00 2022-12-01 00:35:00
50 2022-12-01 00:55:00 2022-12-01 01:05:00
51 2022-12-01 01:15:00 2022-12-01 01:25:00
52 2022-12-01 03:15:00 2022-12-01 03:25:00
53 2022-12-01 03:35:00 2022-12-01 03:45:00
54 2022-12-01 03:45:00 2022-12-01 03:55:00
55 2022-12-01 04:35:00 2022-12-01 05:15:00
56 2022-12-01 05:25:00 2022-12-01 05:35:00
57 2022-12-01 22:05:00 2022-12-01 22:15:00
58 2022-12-01 23:05:00 2022-12-01 23:15:00
59 2022-12-09 07:45:00 2022-12-09 07:55:00
60 2022-12-09 08:05:00 2022-12-09 08:15:00
61 2022-12-09 08:05:00 2022-12-09 08:15:00
62 2022-12-11 15:15:00 2022-12-11 15:35:00
```

Some of these overlap, or are closer than 10 minute apart. What I want to achieve is to merge these events into a single event, so that a new `DataFrame` is generated where no event overlaps with any adjacent event.

I try to identify which time window (capsule) that should be merge with the next, but how to actually merge them?

```py
capsules["Gap to Next"] = -(capsules.End - capsules.Start.shift(-1)) / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
capsules["Merge with Next"] = capsules["Gap to Next"].abs() <= THRS_MERGE
```

Executable code with a binder badge for this example can be found at this gist: https://gist.github.com/Brakjen/92b7196eed941f093fcafc0a9f4e8ef9

[image: Binder]

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Start": [
            "2022-01-05 04:35:00",
            "2022-02-04 21:05:00",
            "2022-03-09 04:35:00",
            "2022-03-09 04:35:00",
            "2022-03-09 20:15:00",
            "2022-03-09 20:25:00",
            "2022-04-27 17:05:00",
            "2022-04-27 17:05:00",
            "2022-04-27 21:05:00",
            "2022-04-27 21:05:00",
            "2022-05-06 12:45:00",
            "2022-05-06 12:45:00",
            "2022-05-06 13:15:00",
            "2022-05-06 13:45:00",
            "2022-05-06 16:50:00",
            "2022-05-06 17:35:00",
            "2022-05-06 22:45:00",
            "2022-05-07 00:45:00",
            "2022-05-07 02:15:00",
            "2022-06-21 06:25:00",
            "2022-06-21 19:25:00",
            "2022-06-21 21:35:00",
            "2022-06-22 15:25:00",
            "2022-06-22 16:15:00",
            "2022-06-22 18:30:00",
            "2022-06-22 19:25:00",
            "2022-06-22 21:05:00",
            "2022-06-23 07:35:00",
            "2022-06-23 07:35:00",
            "2022-07-31 18:35:00",
            "2022-07-31 19:05:00",
            "2022-07-31 19:25:00",
            "2022-07-31 22:00:00",
            "2022-07-31 23:55:00",
            "2022-08-03 23:35:00",
            "2022-08-06 07:20:00",
            "2022-08-08 04:35:00",
            "2022-10-17 12:05:00",
            "2022-10-21 19:05:00",
            "2022-10-22 17:35:00",
            "2022-10-23 07:25:00",
            "2022-11-01 18:25:00",
            "2022-11-01 18:25:00",
            "2022-11-01 23:05:00",
            "2022-11-01 23:05:00",
            "2022-11-02 02:35:00",
            "2022-11-02 03:15:00",
            "2022-11-30 23:45:00",
            "2022-11-30 23:45:00",
            "2022-12-01 00:15:00",
            "2022-12-01 00:55:00",
            "2022-12-01 01:15:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:15:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:35:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:45:00",
            "2022-12-01 04:35:00",
            "2022-12-01 05:25:00",
            "2022-12-01 22:05:00",
            "2022-12-01 23:05:00",
            "2022-12-09 07:45:00",
            "2022-12-09 08:05:00",
            "2022-12-09 08:05:00",
            "2022-12-11 15:15:00",
        ],
        "End": [
            "2022-01-05 04:45:00",
            "2022-02-04 21:15:00",
            "2022-03-09 04:45:00",
            "2022-03-09 04:45:00",
            "2022-03-09 20:25:00",
            "2022-03-09 21:15:00",
            "2022-04-27 17:25:00",
            "2022-04-27 17:15:00",
            "2022-04-27 21:55:00",
            "2022-04-27 21:15:00",
            "2022-05-06 12:55:00",
            "2022-05-06 12:55:00",
            "2022-05-06 13:25:00",
            "2022-05-06 13:55:00",
            "2022-05-06 16:50:00",
            "2022-05-06 17:55:00",
            "2022-05-06 22:55:00",
            "2022-05-07 00:55:00",
            "2022-05-07 02:25:00",
            "2022-06-21 06:35:00",
            "2022-06-21 19:35:00",
            "2022-06-21 21:45:00",
            "2022-06-22 15:55:00",
            "2022-06-22 16:25:00",
            "2022-06-22 18:55:00",
            "2022-06-22 19:35:00",
            "2022-06-22 21:15:00",
            "2022-06-23 07:45:00",
            "2022-06-23 07:45:00",
            "2022-07-31 18:45:00",
            "2022-07-31 19:15:00",
            "2022-07-31 19:35:00",
            "2022-07-31 22:00:00",
            "2022-08-01 00:05:00",
            "2022-08-03 23:45:00",
            "2022-08-06 07:20:00",
            "2022-08-08 04:40:00",
            "2022-10-17 12:15:00",
            "2022-10-21 19:15:00",
            "2022-10-22 17:45:00",
            "2022-10-23 07:35:00",
            "2022-11-01 18:45:00",
            "2022-11-01 18:35:00",
            "2022-11-01 23:15:00",
            "2022-11-01 23:25:00",
            "2022-11-02 03:25:00",
            "2022-11-02 03:25:00",
            "2022-11-30 23:55:00",
            "2022-11-30 23:55:00",
            "2022-12-01 00:35:00",
            "2022-12-01 01:05:00",
            "2022-12-01 01:25:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:25:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:45:00",
            "2022-12-01 03:55:00",
            "2022-12-01 05:15:00",
            "2022-12-01 05:35:00",
            "2022-12-01 22:15:00",
            "2022-12-01 23:15:00",
            "2022-12-09 07:55:00",
            "2022-12-09 08:15:00",
            "2022-12-09 08:15:00",
            "2022-12-11 15:35:00",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Prepare df
df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df["End"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True).sort_values(by="Start")

# Find start values that are less than 10 minutes apart from previous end value
indices = df[(df["Start"].shift(-1) - df["End"]).dt.total_seconds() < 600].index + 1

# Iterate on df to change previous end value and remove next row, recalculate indices
# and iterate again until no more rows that are less than 10 minutes apart are found
while len(indices):
    for idx in indices:
        df.at[idx - 1, "End"] = df.at[idx, "End"]

    df = df.drop(indices).reset_index(drop=True).dropna()
    indices = df[(df["Start"].shift(-1) - df["End"]).dt.total_seconds() < 600].index + 1
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

                 Start                 End
0  2022-01-05 04:35:00 2022-01-05 04:45:00
1  2022-02-04 21:05:00 2022-02-04 21:15:00
2  2022-03-09 04:35:00 2022-03-09 04:45:00
3  2022-03-09 20:15:00 2022-03-09 21:15:00
4  2022-04-27 17:05:00 2022-04-27 17:15:00
5  2022-04-27 21:05:00 2022-04-27 21:15:00
6  2022-05-06 12:45:00 2022-05-06 12:55:00
7  2022-05-06 13:15:00 2022-05-06 13:25:00
8  2022-05-06 13:45:00 2022-05-06 13:55:00
9  2022-05-06 16:50:00 2022-05-06 16:50:00
10 2022-05-06 17:35:00 2022-05-06 17:55:00
11 2022-05-06 22:45:00 2022-05-06 22:55:00
12 2022-05-07 00:45:00 2022-05-07 00:55:00
13 2022-05-07 02:15:00 2022-05-07 02:25:00
14 2022-06-21 06:25:00 2022-06-21 06:35:00
15 2022-06-21 19:25:00 2022-06-21 19:35:00
16 2022-06-21 21:35:00 2022-06-21 21:45:00
17 2022-06-22 15:25:00 2022-06-22 15:55:00
18 2022-06-22 16:15:00 2022-06-22 16:25:00
19 2022-06-22 18:30:00 2022-06-22 18:55:00
20 2022-06-22 19:25:00 2022-06-22 19:35:00
21 2022-06-22 21:05:00 2022-06-22 21:15:00
22 2022-06-23 07:35:00 2022-06-23 07:45:00
23 2022-07-31 18:35:00 2022-07-31 18:45:00
24 2022-07-31 19:05:00 2022-07-31 19:15:00
25 2022-07-31 19:25:00 2022-07-31 19:35:00
26 2022-07-31 22:00:00 2022-07-31 22:00:00
27 2022-07-31 23:55:00 2022-08-01 00:05:00
28 2022-08-03 23:35:00 2022-08-03 23:45:00
29 2022-08-06 07:20:00 2022-08-06 07:20:00
30 2022-08-08 04:35:00 2022-08-08 04:40:00
31 2022-10-17 12:05:00 2022-10-17 12:15:00
32 2022-10-21 19:05:00 2022-10-21 19:15:00
33 2022-10-22 17:35:00 2022-10-22 17:45:00
34 2022-10-23 07:25:00 2022-10-23 07:35:00
35 2022-11-01 18:25:00 2022-11-01 18:35:00
36 2022-11-01 23:05:00 2022-11-01 23:25:00
37 2022-11-02 02:35:00 2022-11-02 03:25:00
38 2022-11-30 23:45:00 2022-11-30 23:55:00
39 2022-12-01 00:15:00 2022-12-01 00:35:00
40 2022-12-01 00:55:00 2022-12-01 01:05:00
41 2022-12-01 01:15:00 2022-12-01 01:25:00
42 2022-12-01 03:15:00 2022-12-01 03:25:00
43 2022-12-01 03:35:00 2022-12-01 03:55:00
44 2022-12-01 04:35:00 2022-12-01 05:15:00
45 2022-12-01 05:25:00 2022-12-01 05:35:00
46 2022-12-01 22:05:00 2022-12-01 22:15:00
47 2022-12-01 23:05:00 2022-12-01 23:15:00
48 2022-12-09 07:45:00 2022-12-09 07:55:00
49 2022-12-09 08:05:00 2022-12-09 08:15:00
50 2022-12-11 15:15:00 2022-12-11 15:35:00
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I notice a couple of cases where this for some reason does not lead to the expected behavior. I will test it again and update the code in gist to showcase what I mean. I have also made another attempt myself which also has a few cases of bad behavior that I need to debug a bit more.